# Spring MVC code- Throws HSEARCH000103 exception when it is being deployed

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, lucene, tomcat7, hibernate-search

In our springmvc website, we are using hibernate search with lucene. There are no issues when i compile the code, but when i try to deploy the code on a tomcat 7.0.52 running on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit server, i get the following exceptions

> INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext Aug 20, 2015
>   1:20:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>   SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userService': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'userManager' while setting constructor argument; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userManager': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   com.atcm.service.impl.UserManagerImpl.setUserDao(com.atcm.dao.UserDao);
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userDao': Injection of resource dependencies
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.SearchException:
>   HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager com.atcm.model.User
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760).............

The hibernate properties file is as follows,

> app.search.index.basedir=target/index
>   hibernate.search.default.directory_provider=filesystem
>   hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy=simple
>   hibernate.search.default.exclusive_index_use=true
>   hibernate.search.lucene_version=LUCENE_35
>   hibernate.search.analyzer=org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer
>   hibernate.search.worker.batch_size=100

Any help , will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this property is intended for development:

```
app.search.index.basedir=target/index
```

Try changing `target/index` for a directory that tomcat can read and write.

Answer (score 0):

Check this property in the configuration file and make sure it points to an existing folder

```
hibernate.search.default.indexBase = path/to/index/folder
```

If the folder exists, check the permissions and make sure you can write on it

For sure, check if this property exists in the hibernate-context

```
<prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">$CONF{hibernate.search.default.indexBase}</prop>
```