# Tomcat7 : INFO: Server startup in 3104 ms

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment, tomcat7, webapp2

I have a maven project deployed on tomcat7 but when i start tomcat it gets stuck at `INFO: Server startup in 3104 ms`. Below in complete log:

```
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 (Ubuntu)
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 27 2016 18:13:17 UTC
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.68.0
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            4.4.0-1013-aws
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /var/lib/tomcat7
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat7
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Xmx1024m
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 812 ms
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 (Ubuntu)
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml has finished in 941 ms
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml has finished in 414 ms
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/examples.xml
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/examples.xml has finished in 814 ms
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/docs.xml
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/docs.xml has finished in 400 ms
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext setPath
WARNING: A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/' and do not end with a '/'. The path [/] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to []
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT has finished in 363 ms
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 26, 2017 5:27:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3026 ms
```

I have gone through [This link](https://serverfault.com/a/655638) that says to change JAVA_OPT but the problem persists even after making that change and restarting the service.

How do stop the server to stop at this and get deployed completely?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. _INFO: Server startup in 3026 ms_ means that startup is complete and your server is now serving content. I would think this is your desired result!

There will be no further logging until you make a request to your server.

Comment: I rechecked after restarting the server there  is some error. Can you have look at [link] http://stackoverflow.com/q/43638748/4248165
and help me to resolve it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [springframework: Error creating bean with name 'userService':](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638748/springframework-error-creating-bean-with-name-userservice)